# In Oracle SQL how to replace multiple char with multiple values?

Tags: sql, oracle

My string is - `ABC Corp., NY., ("Lender") As Agency`
I need to replace comma with `~` and double quotes with `^`.

Required Output - `ABC Corp.~ NY.~ (^Lender^) As Agency`

How do I do it in Oracle 11g SQL using `regexp_replace()`?? Or is there any other way?

Comment: This is a 15 second google search question.

Comment: Simply `translate(col, ',"', '~^')`

Answer (score 1):

The "other way" is to just do two normal replaces

```
select 
 REPLACE(REPLACE('ABC Corp., NY., ("Lender")', ',', '~'), '"', '^') 
from dual
```

Or a TRANSLATE, which is easiest if you only need to switch single characters.

```
select 
 TRANSLATE('ABC Corp., NY., ("Lender")', ',"', '~^') 
from dual
```

Comment: And the "simple other way" uses `translate(col, ',"', '~^')` :-)

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks, I was just adding that.

Answer (score 0):

this will  work:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(yourcolumn,',','~'),'"','^') from yourtable;
```